# Calculating total derivative from partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a univariate function of a multivariate function:
$$F(g(x,y,z)),$$
$$g(x,y,z)=2x+2y+z.$$

I know $F'(x)$, $F'(y)$ and $F'(z)$. I need to know $F'(g)$. How can I do that? I'm confused, but it seems like the chain rule does not work directly here, nor the total derivative as a sum of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule we have
$$\,dF(g)=F'(g)\,dg$$
On the other hand by total derivative rule we get
$$\,dg=g_x\,dx+g_y\,dy+g_z\,dz$$
where $g_x:=\partial g/\partial x$. Therefore
$$\,dF(g)=F'(g)(g_x\,dx+g_y\,dy+g_z\,dz)$$
This then implies for instance 
$$\frac{\,dF(g)}{\,dx}=F'(g)(g_x+g_y\frac{dy}{dx}+g_z\frac{dz}{dx})$$
In particular if $x,y,z$ are independent i.e. $0=dy/dx=dz/dx=...$ one obtains
$$\frac{\,dF(g)}{\,dx}=F'(g)g_x, \frac{\,dF(g)}{\,dy}=F'(g)g_y, \frac{\,dF(g)}{\,dz}=F'(g)g_z$$

Comment: What if $F$ is a function of, say, two $g's$, i.e. $F(g_1(x,y,z), g_2(x,y,z))$?  Can we recover $dF/dg_1$ and $dF/dg_2$ from the partial derivatives $F_x$, $F_y$, $F_z$ and knowledge of the parametric form of $g_1$ and $g_2$?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "$F'(x)$" that you mean that you have a formula for $\frac{d}{dx}\left(F\circ g\right): \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ (your notation is not standard; most people would read $F'(x)$ as "take the derivative of $F$ with respect to its only argument, then plug in $x$" in which case you have nothing you need to do).

If so, you can use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d(F\circ g)}{dx}\left(x,y,z\right) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial g}\left[g(x,y,z)\right]\frac{dg}{dx}(x),$$ which gives

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(F\circ g)}{dx}\left(x,y,z\right) = F'(2x+2y+z),$$

and in particular, setting $x=0,y=0,z=u$,

$$F'(u) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d(F\circ g)}{dx}\left(0,0,u\right).$$

Comment: yes, sorry for the notation error. But then doesn't this mean I have a system of equations, because what you wrote for _x_, we can also write for _y_ and _z_ ?

In a sense, I have your middle equation for both _x_ and _y_, and the same equation, without 1/2 but with 1, for _z_.

I am looking to find out a function for _F'(2x+2y+z)_. The derivatives I have, in relation to _x_, _y_ and _z_ are considered constant.

Comment: @user9486481 you don't need the other equations. Just one will do.